# Remove Home link

Tags: 2013, html, delete

I want to remove the home button from a SharePoint 2013 Site, without it affecting the site collection?

[image: picture of the home page icon]

Comment: Do you want to hide the link with image or just want to remove the link??

Comment: Just remove it is fine.

Comment: Please check my answer below and let me if you face an issue or if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add below CSS in order to hide the Home icon/link from your page:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div#siteIcon {
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

Or (to just remove the link keeping the same in site logo and page title as it is):

```
<style type="text/css">
    div#DeltaSiteLogo {
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

If you want to hide it from only few SharePoint pages or home page of your site then you can add this code in [Script Editor](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/script-editor-web-part-sharepoint/) in your pages.

But, if you want to hide it from everywhere within your site then you need to modify the master page (not recommended).

Comment: To hide it from the whole site collection , "Alternate CSS URL" can be used which is technically not modifying the master page. Correct me if I am wrong ?

Comment: Yes that can be done. But I guess Zach is trying to remove it for only one site "without affecting the site collection".